# mysql_real_escape_string() leaves slashes to my image tag when re submitting page

Tags: php, mysql-real-escape-string

```
$a = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_list_words($a));

$query = "update r set answer='{$a}' WHERE id = '{$id}'";
```

When the page gets "saved" (re-submitted) the frame that the "answer" (image) is display goes from:

> img src="/Images.php?imageId=b9129d0e96f1be14a4a0" alt="test5.png"

TO

> img src="\"/maint/reportsImages.php?imageId=b9129d0e96f1be14a4a0\"" alt="\"test5.png\"">

How can I convert this or change the way it gets saved/refreshed with mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: you probably have magic_quotes enabled and things are getting multi-escaped. That means you're on a massively outdated and/or badly configured PHP. Plus, m_r_e_s would not *ADD* quotes to the string. there's no way `alt="test5"` would get converted to `alt="\"\"test5.png\"\""` by m_r_e_s.

Comment: You should probably be using PDO and prepared statements, and then you wouldn't have to worry about this in the first place.

Comment: Your query looks off `$query = "update r set answer='{$a"} WHERE id = '{$id}';` where it should probably read as `$query = "update r set answer='{$a}' WHERE id = '{$id}'";`

Comment: It only messes up the image tag when I add text to the field and then save.  If there is just an image there and I click save, it stays the same.

Comment: or you can try stripslashes http://in3.php.net/stripslashes

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**warning**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
  $a= stripslashes($a);
}
if (function_exists('mysql_real_escape_string')) {
  $query = mysql_real_escape_string($a);
} else {
  $query =  mysql_escape_string($a);
}
```

Comment: this works, unless im missing the escape string completely

Comment: Can you put your `var_dump($query);`?

Comment: this works, I dont know why some one downvoted

Comment: +1 for the fact that it works, and I hate it when someone downvotes without comment.  But you should really use parameterized queries.

Comment: Wasn't me, but a couple thoughts: 1) Good answers should have some explanation of why/how they solve the problem, not just a code dump. 2) Continuing to use mysql_ functions is 2014 is hugely irresponsible (vs. simply using bound parameters) and as this question/answers demonstrates, leads to needlessly verbose code. Some people try to discourage continued use of code like this.

Comment: @AndrewMedico I agree this is not best practice... that being said, some people (like myself) think it's also important to discourage commentless downvotes...